# Twitter API devolver una lista de seguidores mas larga que 70.000

Tags: twitter-api, twitter

Usando TwitterOauth , estoy tratando de obtener una lista de seguidores de una cuenta con una gran lista de seguidores. Como la API devuelve no más de 5000 usuarios por request, siguiendo el consejo de otras respuestas , trate de usar cursores, pero ahora me encuentro con el problema de que solo puedo hacer "15 requests per window", asi que solo puedo obtener los ultimos 70.000 seguidores. Pense en guardar el cursor y hacer llamados 15 minutos despues, pero la API devuelve el seguidor mas reciente primero, asi que guardar el cursor lo vuelve impreciso. Que puedo hacer para devolver una lista de seguidores cuando es mas grande que 70.000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [GET users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) para obtener la cantidad de seguidores (`followers_count`).

Con dicha información de una ejecución a otra, sabes si debes leer la primera página o no de la consulta de la lista de seguidores.

Si debes consultar la primera página, cargas sólo aquellos que no están repetidos.

Luego vas a la página pendiente de tu última ejecución. Esta página puede contener información repetida que no deberías cargar (el desplazamiento producido por los nuevos seguidores). Luego continuas cargando las páginas, hasta alcanzar el límite de esa ejecución.

Y te guardas la próxima página que debes leer para utilizar en tu próxima ejecución.